# NSURLSession in main thread

Tags: mysql, ios, multithreading

I'm attempting to download data from MySQL. However when NSURLSession creates a new thread, the data hasn't completely downloaded and thus the main thread is dealing with null values / crashes.  I've used GCD's dispatch_async, however it's a few milliseconds slow.

In my test program, I have two NSLogs, one directly after calling the NSURLSession method and the other in the method itself. The output (below) shows NSURLSession is delayed by 30 milliseconds. Although while the time itself isn't much, it would have an enormous impact in how I'll structure my task. Is there any way to pause the main thread until the data has been downloaded and the method has been finished?

```
2014-03-30 18:56:06.224 TestProgram[1396:60b] (null) 
2014-03-30 18:56:06.258 TestProgram[1396:60b] [{"error":200}]
```

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
    if(error == nil)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"%@",text);

            NSError *error;

            self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

            for(int i =0 ; i < self.json.count ; i++)
            {
                [dataParse setDictionary:_json[i]];
            }
        });
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
    }
}];

[dataTask resume];
```

Comment: I am now thinking it would be to notify a delegate in the view controller that the data has been downloaded and update the VC accordingly. Thoughts?

Comment: You never should do network requests synchronously (i.e. don't make the main thread wait for the network request). You should show us the code that is crashing, but the general idea is that you initiate the tasks that require the data inside the `completionHandler` of the network request, not after it.

Comment: Ah cheers. The reason it was crashing was the NSDictionary had no keys by the name I was looking for.

Comment: Then your code that is looking for those dictionary entries should check for `nil` and handle that appropriately (rather than trying to change the network request to be synchronous). If you use synchronous requests, the app will be less responsive and possibly subject to being killed by watchdog process.

Comment: Thank you. However handing nil values would not fix my immediate problem discussed in the OP. The reason I was getting nil values was due to the lag in the network request. Handling that would require starting a new request to bring in the data needed. In doing so, I would be starting a new request that isn't necessary.

Thank you for your input. I will put in a delegate method in the morning. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for the NSURLSessionDataTask completion routine. It seems to imply that the data is not completely downloaded at that point.